# Add keyboard event listeners in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, event-handling

I read the documentation of vue but can't figure out what is the proper way to add keyboard event listener to my app. It just shows how to add one for input elements. I have something like:

```
<div>
  <p>Some content</p>
  <button>Go left</button>
  <button>Go right</button>
</div>
```

I want to add an keyboard event listener so that when a user presses ← it goes left and → goes right.
It works for the button event listener, but I don't know how to make it work for keyboard.

Should I do `document.addEventListener()` or `window.addEventListener()`? I don't need the event listener for the whole app, just for that `div`.

Comment: You could use `Vue` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work as expected. You just have to make sure your button is focused.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
   squack: function(text){
     alert(text)
    }
  },
  directives: {
    focus: {
      inserted(el) {
        el.focus()
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
<div>
  <p>Some content</p>
  <button @keyup.left="squack('left button clicked')" v-focus>Go left</button>
  <button @keyup.right="squack('right button clicked')">Go right</button>
</div>
</div>
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjo6nfhL/) for example. Make sure you shift focus between buttons with Tab / Shift+Tab.

Comment: Check the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjo6nfhL/). Press the left keyboard key and you should get an alert window. Shift focus to the `Go right` button 
 by pressing Tab, then press the right keyboard key. You should also get an alert window.

Comment: Can we activate the squack method without having to focus the button?

Comment: I don't think that's possible unfortunately. The element has to be in focus for it to receive the event. You'd have to attach your events to another element such as a container div.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful

Comment: @Rocke having tab index for whole `div` and applying keyboard event listeners to that `div` can help to achieve what you desire. I'll  make a new answer for it

Answer (score 2):

See this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajitid/cjo6nfhL/5/).

Keyboard events work only when you have focus on that element. So having focus on whole `<div>` and having keyboard events can help. This also eliminates any need of those two left-right buttons. Elements like `<button>` and `<a>` have the ability to get focused, `<div>` doesn't. So we manually need to add tab index to it.

Learn more about tab index [from here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/focus/using-tabindex).

Comment: I utilize document.addEventListener("keydown",someFunction) to accomplish what I want. In this way I don't need to focus the div. Thank you for your answer.